# error: invalid operands of types ‘double*’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator/’

Tags: c++

I have my program and I am using g++ compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double getCal(double *par);

int main() {
    double final_price;
    double discount;
    discount = 12;

    final_price = getCal(&discount);
    cout << "final price for you is" << final_price << endl;

    return 0;
}

double getCal(double *par) {
    double original_price;
    double r;

    cout << " enter the price" << endl;
    cin >> original_price;

    r= (par/100.00);
    return original_price - (original_price*r);
}
```

I have checked reference for cmath but I haven't noticed division function that would replace my operator.Both par and 100.00 are doubles.What should I CHANGE?

Comment: The message is very clear, are you intentionally ignoring it? `par` is `double*` not `double`

Comment: `Both par and 100.00 are doubles.` No, par is a `double*`, i.e. "pointer to double".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`par` is not a double but a pointer to a double. If you want to divide the value (pointed to by `par`) you have to write

```
r = *par / 100.0;
```

However, there is no need to pass by pointer and maybe you should better change the signature from

```
double getCal(double *par)
```

to

```
double getCal(double par) //(1)
```

unless you really need a reference inside the function. And even then, you still should stay away from pointers and pass a reference:

```
double getCal(double& par)
```

Just for the sake of completeness I also mention the common way to pass-by-value:

```
double getCal(const double& par)
```

However, with a single double value the difference between this and (1) is most likely negligible.